# How to pass a second route parameter to angular 2 services module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am new to angular 2 and would appreciate input on how to pass multiple parameters to angular's service module. For example here is the first param that i am passing to the service via the router link.

home-component.html

```
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/product', product.slug]">
```

which is mapped to the route defined below in app.routes.ts and loads the ProductOverviewComponent.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'product/:slug', component: ProductOverviewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

product-overview.component.ts calls the `getProductOverview()` method.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    let slug = params['slug'];
    console.log('getting product with slug: ', slug);
    this.productoverviewservice.getProductOverview(slug)
    .subscribe(p => this.product = p);
  });
}
```

which calls the getProductOverview method from product-overview.service.ts

```
getProductOverview(slug: string): Observable<Course> {
    let product$ = this.http
        .get(`${this.baseUrl}${slug}/` , options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

My question is how to I pass a second route parameter to the function getProductDetail?

for example:

```
getProductDetail(slug: string): Observable<Course> {
    let productDetail$ = this.http
        .get(`${this.baseUrl}${slug}/${slug2}` , options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the routing like this:

```
{path: 'product/:slug/:slug2', component: ProductOverviewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }])
```

And it should works!

Comment: Yes man thanks it loads the new component! I have a follow up question!

Comment: Perfect @dave I asked because I didn't see any validation to the answer, I'll check the new question!

Comment: just a note @OctavioGarbarino - path cannot start with a slash. at least in RC6.

Comment: you are right! I will fix it, in the the places with "redirectTo:" I do have slash at start and is working properly, is it OK? Thanks @mrgoos !

Comment: Cool @OctavioGarbarino, in `redirectTo` the slash is also not needed. I saw a section in ng2 docs where it appears with slash and a different section where it isn't. In my code I don't have slash and it is working.

Comment: @OctavioGarbarino - I have just stumbled upon this article from the maker of NG2. According to this, slash implies for an ABSOLUTE REDIRECTS URL as opposed to a relative one:
http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes